# Does Windows support IPComp?

Tags: windows-7, ipsec, windows-8.1

The title says it all. I've configured an IPSec IKEv2 connection between a Strongswan server and a Windows 7 workstation and I'd like to use compression if possible.

The config on both sides is dead simple and uses public key authentication (machine certificate on the workstation) :

```
conn rw
 left=1.2.3.4
 leftid=example.com
 leftcert=cert.der
 leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
 leftfirewall=yes
 right=%any
 rightid="C=FR, O=Example Company, CN=workstation"
 rightsourceip=2.3.4.5
 rightdns=6.7.8.9
 keyexchange=ikev2
 esp=aes128-sha256
 ike=aes128-sha256-modp2048
 compress=yes # compression is enabled
 auto=add
```

Yet, I always see "Compression: 0 %" on the Windows client, and a search for "windows ipcomp" doesn't produce any relevant results like an official MSDN page, only this [page from 2010](http://www.jacco2.dds.nl/networking/openswan-l2tp.html#compression) claiming that Windows (which one?) doesn't support IPComp.

Did anything change since then, do the newer versions of Windows support it (finally a decent reason to upgrade to this Windows 8 crap) ?